# Prove that for any real non-singular matrix $Q$, the product $QQ^T$ is a positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

For any real non-singular matrix $Q$, the product $QQ^T$ is a positive definite matrix.

If an $n×n$ $n×n$ symmetric $Q$ is positive definite, then all of its eigenvalues are positive, so $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $Q$....
 I don't know if I'm on thy good way to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the fact that if $x$ and $y$ are vectors and $\langle x,y\rangle$ denotes their dot product then $\langle Qx,y\rangle = \langle x,Q^Ty\rangle$. This is a general property of the transpose of a real matrix, called *adjointness*. Anyway, we have that
$$
\langle QQ^T x, x\rangle = \langle Q^Tx, Q^Tx\rangle.
$$
What can you say about the signs of these expressions? What does *positive-definite* mean? What does *non-singular* mean? Do you see why this equation gives you enough material to finish the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't know exactly how to finish it, but thank you for your comment